# Update database of button click in laravel form

Tags: php, database, forms, laravel-4

I have this on my view

```
{{ Form::open() }}
@if($order->paid == 0)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">Mark Order as Paid</a>
@else
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="0">Mark Order as Unpaid</a>
@endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

And this in my controller

```
public function ordersPaidSubmit($orderId) {       
    $order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->first();
    if (!$order) {
        App::abort(404);
}

    $paid = Input::get('paid');
    $order->save();

    return Redirect::to('/admin/orders');
}
```

Is it possible to give value to buttons `0` or`1` like this and on click to update database column? Currently doesn't update but how can be make to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put one hidden field in each button like this:

```
{{ Form::open() }}
@if($order->paid == 0)
    {{ Form::hidden('paid', 1, ['id' => 'paid']) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="1">Mark Order as Paid</a>
@else
    {{ Form::hidden('paid', 0, ['id' => 'paid']) }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="0">Mark Order as Unpaid</a>
@endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

So hidden field will looks like

```
<input id="paid" name="paid" type="hidden" value="1">
and
<input id="paid" name="paid" type="hidden" value="0">
```

I'm sure that you want to use `$order` not `$paid` in your controller. So change this line

```
$paid = Input::get('paid');
```

whit

```
$order->paid = Input::get('paid');
```

And your form buttons will work.